# unit testing in javascript: how do you mock? - a (hard for me) example

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, qunit, vows

I just rewrote [backbone-mongodb](https://github.com/ToolPartTeam/backbone-mongodb) to be really compatible with backbone. The original solution had nice vows for testing, and I would like my code to get tested as well, but simply have no idea how to do it.

Here is an example, I would like to test:

```
update: function(callback) {

var model = this.model;

this._withCollection(function(err, collection) {
  if (err) callback(err);
  else {
    var attributes = _.clone(model.attributes);
    delete attributes['_id'];
    collection.update({ _id: new ObjectID(model.id) }, {$set: attributes}, {safe:true, upsert:false}, function(err) {
      model.fetch();
      callback(null, model.toJSON());
    });
  }
});


},
```

This code has nothing special in it. It uses the node-mongodb-native driver, and updates a record in the database. AFAIK, proper testing would mean to at least check that (1) `collection.update` was called with the given arguments, (2) `callback` is called when and how it should be, (3) model contains the new data.

With vows I can check (2), but have no idea at all how to check (1). Actually, the same holds for every unit testing framework I know about, qUnit, Jasmine. I'm sure that this can be done somehow, and I'm decided to learn at least one of them, but it's hard to make a choice when you got stuck at the beginning. :)

I know about sinon.js and think that everyting can be tested using mocking all the objects I have until I end up having the collection mocked as well, but this seems to be extremely clumsy. Could someone help me in writing the above tests please, and I'll happy to write out a tutorial of it?

Comment: how is collection and model being passed into the update class?

Comment: You can see the call to `_withCollection`. Actually, I set a `this.collectionName` variable, and `_withCollection` retrieves the collection given its name, and calls the callback with the returned collection.
It's a common approach with node.js. You use callbacks everywhere as the framework is totally asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

I will use [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) for that purpose; I don't how familiar are you using that library, but they have a plugin to use [jQuery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) for writing spec tests, you can load fixtures/templates and run tests on it.

for your particular case, assuming that function is part of MyObj "class", I will write something like:

```
describe("My object tests", function() {

   it("Should update my obj", function () {
     var noError, flag = false;
     MyObj.update(function (err, model){
       flag=true;
       noError= err==null;
       // or you can do other checks on the result
     })

     // we wait for 5 sec until get a response (flag==true)
     waitsFor(function (){ return flag}, "Timeout on update", 5000);

     // check if there are no errors
     expect(noError).toBeTruthy();
   });

});
```